# Как узнать, у кого наибольший рейтинг сообщений по определённой метке?

Tags: поддержка, метки, знаки, голоса-за

Сегодня заработал бронзовый знак за метку [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), т.е. за мои ответы проголосовало 100 человек (ну или точнее 100 раз). Как узнать, у кого наибольшее количество таких очков на:

- ru.SO
- Meta.ru.SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В описании метки, например, упомянутой выше [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), есть прямая ссылка на [список лучших участников](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers):

> [image: Лучшие участники]

В списке присутствуют как авторы вопросов, так и авторы ответов.

Answer (score 6):

1. Нажать на метку
2. Нажать "подробнее"
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В блоке "Лучшие авторы ответов" нажать "еще"
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итого попадаем в [список лучших участников по метке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers)

Comment: На картинке стрелка показывает на описание метки. Нужно перенаправить стрелку на **Лучшие участники**

Comment: Я написал тот порядок действий о котором знал, вы предлагаете другой